# Info/Code Collapsing(Folding, Minimization)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

One useful tool that I think would be nice to include is a way to minimize info.

Example:

> ► My Code

[ **click** ]

> ▼ My Code
>
> > Original:
> >     `sout("text")`
> >     New:`System.out.println("text")`

as well as code-folding
Example:

`⊞ void foo(){...}`

[ **click** ]

```
⊟ void foo(){ 
    System.out.println("Hello World!!!")
}
```

This could be implemented using this example syntax:

> ```
> [+] Click Me!(to see)  [-]  You Clicked Me!! Now you can see! |
>    ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓      ↓
> ```
>
> > ► **Click Me!(to see)**
> >
> > ▼ **You Clicked Me!! Now you can see!**

and in a code block similar things could happen except ⊞⊟ would show up instead.

> ```
> [+] public void foo(){...}  [-]  public void foo(){
>        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
>     } |
>    ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓     ↓      ↓
> ```
>
> > `⊞ public void foo(){...}`
> >
> > `⊟ public void foo(){
> >          System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
> >     }`

so the syntax would be `[+] ... [-] ... |` and would act as a switch with either [`►`,`▼`] or [`⊞`,`⊟`] to show the switch.

Any other Suggestions?

Comment: So, you're saying we could take one of the most-loathed features of IDEs (code folding) and integrate it here? Sure, I guess we *could*...

Answer (score 5):

Anything that is relevant to the question should be shown by default.
Anything that is *not* relevant to the question **should not be in the question**.

This suggestion would encourage users to either:

- hide relevant information, or
- include irrelevant information.

So no, I don't think this suggestion should be implemented.

Comment: I would imagine this would be more useful in answers than questions. For example, one could use it to give a detailed explanation to a part of the answer that is by default glossed over. (Note that I'm not in favor of the idea, but your rejection isn't convincing to me.)

Comment: It would be more for hiding things like _proof of research_ or in situations in which the user is confused about what should and should not be included or where the code is shown because it would otherwise be hard to understand why something doesn't work. I do know that this feature could be somewhat abused however if the number and levels of a nesting are limited it would help users to know what info is missing and what info is there. Also this feature could be limited by reputation points to prevent abuse.